# " ']' expected " error when assigning a value to an element of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, syntax-error, double

When i try to assign a value to an element of a 2d array, it gives me "']' expected" error .So far i have tried;
Changing the data type of my array, 
Changing the name of my array,
Changing my IDE ( From Apache NetBeans to Eclipse.Same error except it says ';' expected instead of ']')

Searched it but could not come up with a solution . Here is the code sample ;

> EDIT: problem solved , thanks .

```
public class Datas{

    double[][] matrix= new double[2][2];
   matrix[0][0]=1;
   matrix[0][1]=1;
   matrix[0][2]=1;
   matrix[1][0]=1;
   matrix[1][1]=1;
   matrix[1][2]=1;
   matrix[2][0]=1;
   matrix[2][1]=1;
   matrix[2][2]=1;
     }
```

Comment: This is clearly a syntax error - your assignments are not within a method body;

Answer (score 1):

The initialisation should be in a function.
Probably, for your use case you can do it in Constructor.

```
public class Datas {

    double[][] matrix = new double[2][2];

    Datas() {
        matrix[0][0] = 1;
        matrix[0][1] = 1;
        matrix[0][2] = 1;
        matrix[1][0] = 1;
        matrix[1][1] = 1;
        matrix[1][2] = 1;
        matrix[2][0] = 1;
        matrix[2][1] = 1;
        matrix[2][2] = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every line except `double[][] matrix= new double[2][2];` must reside in a method.

If this is a POJO, put them in the constructor.

```
public class Datas{

  double[][] matrix= new double[2][2];

  public Datas() {
    matrix[0][0]=1;
    matrix[0][1]=1;
    matrix[0][2]=1;
    matrix[1][0]=1;
    matrix[1][1]=1;
    matrix[1][2]=1;
    matrix[2][0]=1;
    matrix[2][1]=1;
    matrix[2][2]=1;
  }
}
```

Otherwise you'll need a `main`. Although - there are better/easier ways to init every value in a 2D array to 1:

```
Arrays.fill(matrix, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can set these values in constructor of the class

```
public class Datas {

    double[][] matrix = new double[2][2];

    public Datas() {
        matrix[0][0] = 1;
        matrix[0][1] = 1;
        matrix[0][2] = 1;
        matrix[1][0] = 1;
        matrix[1][1] = 1;
        matrix[1][2] = 1;
        matrix[2][0] = 1;
        matrix[2][1] = 1;
        matrix[2][2] = 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a constructor, you can also use an Instance Initializer block right next to the array declaration:

```
public class Datas {

    double[][] matrix = new double[2][2];
    {
        matrix[0][0] = 1;
        matrix[0][1] = 1;
        matrix[0][2] = 1;
        matrix[1][0] = 1;
        matrix[1][1] = 1;
        matrix[1][2] = 1;
        matrix[2][0] = 1;
        matrix[2][1] = 1;
        matrix[2][2] = 1;
    }
}
```